# HTML not recognizing display:none for element

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a webpage using Python Flask, and I want the webpage to display an image during the loading period after a user submits a form. I've attempted set the element "loading_gif" to display as none until the form is clicked, and then the javascript function on the top should make it displayable while the background content becomes hidden.

The problem is that when I load the webpage, the image is already there. After submitting a form, the background content disappears and the image remains, so the JS function seems to be working correctly. I'm just not sure why the image isn't hidden in the beginning.

In the img { display:none} section, I've tried using loading_gif instead of img and #loading_gif, but neither works either.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function loading(){
        document.getElementById("loading_gif").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("content").style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;

img {
    display: none;
}

</style>

<body>
    <img id = "loading_gif" src="{{url_for('static', filename='image.gif')}}">
    <div id = "content">
        <h1><center>Track Your Packages!</center></h1>
        <center>UPS, USPS, or FedEx</center>

        <form method = "POST">
                <input type = "text", placeholder = "Add Tracking Number", name = "AddTrackingNum">
                <input class = "btn btn-primary" type = "submit", onclick = "loading(); return False;">
        </form>
        <form method = "POST">
                <input type = "text", placeholder = "Remove Tracking Number", name = "RemoveTrackingNum">
                <input class = "btn btn-primary" type = "submit">
        </form>
        <body>Last update: {{current_dateTime}}</body>
                <div class="container" style="min-height:100% width:80%">
                {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
                  {% if messages %}
                    {% for message in messages %}
                      <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                        {{message}}
                      </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                  {% endif %}
                {% endwith %}

                {% block body %}{% endblock %}
                </div>


              <table>
               <tr>
                <th>Company</th>
                <th>Tracking Number</th>
                <th>Location</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>As of </th>
                <th>Scheduled Delivery Date</th>
               </tr>

               {%for i in tableDict%}
               <tr>
                   {%for y in tableDict[i]%}
                     <td>{{y}}</td>
                   {%endfor%}
                 {%endfor%}
               </tr>

              </table>
        </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: add `#loading_gif{display:none}` to the css

Comment: Your style beginning with tr:nth-child(even) doesn't appear to have a closing brace, which means your img style is being ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because of an syntax issue, you need to close "tr:nth-child(even)" brace
Style should look as follwing:

```
<style>
table {
 font-family: arial, sans-serif;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 width: 100%;
}

td, th {
 border: 1px solid #dddddd;
 text-align: left;
 padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
 background-color: #dddddd;
}

img {
 display: none;
}
</style>
```